# Most Rails way to render view content in a worker thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to generate an HTML newsletter and batch sync it to a bulk email provider.

I have a Rake task which synchonizes all the contacts, and need to generate the newsletter HTML. I am presented with several options, non of them perfect:

1. I can generate it using a controller. This seems most correct but means I hit the webstack hard.
2. I can hack a model to allow it to parse a haml file and generate the content. This feels bad but would let me generate it from a worker.

There must be a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it from a model. If you need to generate a newsletter, the newsletter is an email, so use a mailer. If your content is user-specific, then pass the needed data to the mailer notification method. The mailer inherites from ActionDispatch::Base, that means you have access to the rendering engine, HAML, Slim, ERB, whatever you are using. After you're done testing and developing building user-specific emails, you should create a rake task that r builds and sends a newsletter to each user. After having this task, you can map it to a cron job which will execute it automatically in production whenever you decide.

Just don't let the whole MVC mountain in Rails fool you, the newsletter is a completely different beast, it doesn't belong in the application logic.

Comment: I don't need the mailer to send the mail though, I just need to generate the HTML. This gets passed to the email sender via an API in a batch job...

Comment: true, you don't. But it's a much better idea than doing it from a model. All you need is a rendering engine, pass your template with the respective locals to it, and then use a mailer client (gem [mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail), for instance)